# Carriage returns in html table

Tags: html, sql, asp.net, html-table

I am having problems displaying returns in the html table, it returns as one line.

I am getting the data from an sql 2012 database but it is strange because when I edit the data in a text area it shows the returns.

Any ideas?

```
 public ActionResult Details(int id = 0)
    {
        WorkoutModel workoutmodel = db.WorkoutModels.Find(id);
        if (workoutmodel == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(workoutmodel.WorkoutDetails.Replace(System.Environment.NewLine, "<br />"));
    }
```

Comment: Set a breakpoint and see what exactly is the value of `workoutmodel.WorkoutDetails`

Comment: `Environment.NewLine` has issues sometimes. I have updated the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Text areas will show returns properly but you will have to parse the returns to breaks in the HTML.

As in:

```
My text with a \r\nLine break.
```

Becomes:

```
My text with a <br />Line break.
```

Comment: I am displaying data that a user has input though so I want to show returns from what they input. I cant really edit every post with a load of <br />

Comment: @user3317526 You don't need to edit every post. You just modify it when you display the post in HTML. Refer my answer.

Comment: I eddited my post to show you how i tried to do it but I am havin no luck

Answer (score 1):

While displaying data from the database you have to replace line breaks with HTML line breaks using the code below.

```cs
return View(workoutmodel.WorkoutDetails.Replace("\r\n", "<br />")
                                       .Replace("\n", "<br />")
                                       .Replace("\r", "<br />"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I go this route because "\n" is part of newline across the major operating systems (Windows \r\n, Mac and *nix \n). It replaces the \n character and cleans up any \r that may be left behind (not that they generally do any harm being left behind in HTML).

```
valueFromDb.Replace("\n", "<br />").Replace("\r", "");
```